# Link to leanModal.js works fine in rendered by HTML link but not within React

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

I am using Lean Modal: http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/ in a Rails app with a React front-end.

When I put the link to the modal in application.html.erb it works fine but when loaded through a React link using the same code, nothing happens.

I have jQuery loaded and checked 10 times if the code is the same. What could cause such an issue?

Here is the link code in React:

```
<a rel="leanModal" name="login" href="#login">
```

The template file (html.erb) script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('a[rel*=leanModal]').leanModal({ top : 200, closeButton: ".modal_close" });       
    });
```

And I am loading the modal JS from my application.js file in Rails.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: When rendering via React, the link probably doesn't exist when the jQuery code fires. It's rendered and attached to the DOM at a later time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The other reply seems to confirm you were correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap things that interact with DOM (e.g. jQuery plugins) in a component.

```
var LeanModal = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function(){
        $(this.getDOMNode()).leanModal({
           top: this.props.top || 200
        });    
    },
    render: function(){
        return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
    }
});
```

Note that you also need to provide a componentWillUnmount to handle clean up, and that the plugin can't do things like add/remove elements.  Plugins that don't allow cleanup or make destructive changes are incompatible with react.

Sometimes implementing it with just the existing CSS and using react components instead of the jQuery plugin can be very simple and end up with a better result.